# Read JAX-RS body InputStream twice

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a JAX-RS logging filter to log request and response details, something like this:

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        ...
        String body = getBody(request);           
        ...
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("request: {}", httpRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

The `getBody()` method reads the body content from the `InputStream` but I need to do some trick because I can not reset this stream. Without this little trick my rest methods always receive empty request body content:

```
private String getBody(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    try {
        byte[] body = IOUtils.toByteArray(requestContext.getEntityStream());

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);
        requestContext.setEntityStream(stream);

        return new String(body);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to read the body content?

Comment: Refer Interceptors and Filters section at [link](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter12/reader_and_writer_interceptors.html)

Comment: @Gautam - Can you elaborate on what that documentation points out that the question asker is missing?

Comment: This might help as well as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924990/how-to-cache-inputstream-for-multiple-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** Here's an improved version that seem much more robust and use JDK classes. Just invoke `close()` before reusing.

```
    public class CachingInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {    
    public CachingInputStream(InputStream source) {
        super(new PostCloseProtection(source));
        super.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        if (!((PostCloseProtection) in).decoratedClosed) {
            in.close();
        }
        super.reset();
    }

    private static class PostCloseProtection extends InputStream {
        private volatile boolean decoratedClosed = false;
        private final InputStream source;

        public PostCloseProtection(InputStream source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? 0 : source.skip(n);
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            return source.available();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            decoratedClosed = true;
            source.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void mark(int readLimit) {
            source.mark(readLimit);
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() throws IOException {
            source.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean markSupported() {
            return source.markSupported();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows to read the whole stream in the buffer, by tweaking the `mark` to `Integer.MAXVALUE`. This also makes sure that the source is properly closed on the first close to free up OS resource.

---

**Old Answer**

As you can't be sure the actual implementation of the `InputStream` support mark (`markSupported()`). You're better of caching the input stream itself in a first apprach.

For exemple in a `ContainerRequestFilter` :

```
@Component
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Priority(1)
public class ReadSomethingInPayloadFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        CachingInputStream entityStream = new CachingInputStream(request.getEntityStream());

        readPayload(entityStream);

        request.setEntityStream(entityStream.getCachedInputStream());
    }
}
```

The caching input stream is a naive approach to input stream caching, it is way similar to your approach :

```
class CachingInputStream extends InputStream {
    public static final int END_STREAM = -1;
    private final InputStream is;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public CachingInputStream(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public InputStream getCachedInputStream() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int result = is.read();
        // Avoid rewriting the end char (-1) otherwise it will be considered as a real char.
        if (result != END_STREAM)
            baos.write(result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return is.available();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        is.close();
    }

}
```

This implementation is naive in various ways, it can be improved in the following area and probably more :

- Check `markSupported` on the original stream
- Don't use the heap to store the cached input stream, this would avoid pressure on the GC
- Cache is unbounded currently this may be a good improvement, at the very least use the same bounds as your http server.